# FBX SDK Transformation/Scaling

Tags: c++, fbx, vulkan

I am using the FBX SDK to load 3d models into my rendering application. I can successfully traverse the object hierarchy and pull vertex data for the individual scene meshes and display the meshes in their proper locations and rotations but I am having trouble with scaling. I believe I need to apply a transformation to the mesh before extracting vertex data so that it will extract vertex positions based on the transformation but not sure how to do this. Currently I am rotating the meshes down-stream in the rendering application and would prefer to apply rotation to the meshes before pulling vertex data, this way I can pull vertices that have xyz data based on the proper mesh rotation/scale. I have attached my code for reference. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
#pragma once

#define FBXSDK_SHARED
#include <fbxsdk.h>

struct FBXMesh {
    std::vector<Vertex> Vertices = {};
    std::vector<uint32_t> Indices = {};

    const char* Texture_Diffuse = "";

    FbxDouble3 translation;
    FbxDouble3 rotation;
    FbxDouble3 scaling;

    ~FBXMesh() {
        printf("Destroy FBX Mesh\n");
        Vertices.clear();
        Indices.clear();
    }
};

struct FBXObject {
    std::vector<FBXMesh*> Meshes = {};

    FBXObject() {}

    ~FBXObject() {
        printf("Destroy FBX Object\n");
        for (auto M : Meshes) {
            delete M;
        }
    }
};

class ImportFBX {
    std::unordered_map<const char*, FBXObject*> _FbxObjects;
public:
    FbxManager* _FbxManager = nullptr;

    ImportFBX() {
        _FbxManager = FbxManager::Create();
        FbxIOSettings* _FbxSettings = FbxIOSettings::Create(_FbxManager, IOSROOT);
        _FbxManager->SetIOSettings(_FbxSettings);
    }

    ~ImportFBX() {
        _FbxManager->Destroy();
    }

    void EmptyCache() {
        for (auto FBX : _FbxObjects) {
            delete FBX.second;
        }
        _FbxObjects.clear();
    }

    //  Only the first UV set is used for each mesh
    FBXObject* Import(const char* File) {
        if (_FbxObjects.count(File) == 1) {
            return _FbxObjects[File];
        }
        else {
            printf("[FBX]: Load %s\n", File);
            FbxImporter* Importer = FbxImporter::Create(_FbxManager, "");
            if (!Importer->Initialize(File, -1, _FbxManager->GetIOSettings())) {
                printf("FBX Import Initialize Failed: %s", Importer->GetStatus().GetErrorString());
                return nullptr;
            }
            FbxScene* Scene = FbxScene::Create(_FbxManager, "NewScene");
            Importer->Import(Scene);
            Importer->Destroy();
            fbxsdk::FbxGeometryConverter(_FbxManager).Triangulate(Scene, true);

            //
            //  Find Root Node and traverse all children
            FbxNode* RootNode = Scene->GetRootNode();
            if (RootNode) {
                std::vector<fbxsdk::FbxNode*> Nodes;

                for (unsigned int i = 0; i < RootNode->GetChildCount(); i++) {
                    fbxsdk::FbxNode* Child = RootNode->GetChild(i);
                    const fbxsdk::FbxNodeAttribute* Attribute = Child->GetNodeAttribute();
                    if (Attribute == NULL) { continue; }

                    const FbxNodeAttribute::EType AttributeType = Attribute->GetAttributeType();
                    if (AttributeType != FbxNodeAttribute::eMesh) { continue; }
                    
                    Nodes.push_back(Child);
                }

                printf("\t%i Nodes - %zi Usable\n", RootNode->GetChildCount(true), Nodes.size());
                FBXObject* NewFBX = _FbxObjects.emplace(File, new FBXObject).first->second;

                for (auto Node : Nodes) {
                    FBXMesh* NewMesh = new FBXMesh;
                    NewFBX->Meshes.push_back(NewMesh);

                    const char* nodeName = Node->GetName();
                    NewMesh->translation = Node->LclTranslation.Get();
                    NewMesh->rotation = Node->LclRotation.Get();
                    NewMesh->scaling = Node->LclScaling.Get();

                    // Print the contents of the node.
                    printf("<node '%s'\n\ttranslation=(%f, %f, %f) \n\trotation=(%f, %f, %f) \n\tscale=(%f, %f, %f)>\n",
                        nodeName,
                        NewMesh->translation[0], NewMesh->translation[1], NewMesh->translation[2],
                        NewMesh->rotation[0], NewMesh->rotation[1], NewMesh->rotation[2],
                        NewMesh->scaling[0], NewMesh->scaling[1], NewMesh->scaling[2]
                    );
                    //
                    //  Material Information
                    const int Materials = Node->GetSrcObjectCount<FbxSurfaceMaterial>();
                    printf("\tMaterials %i\n", Materials);
                    const FbxSurfaceMaterial* Material = FbxCast<const FbxSurfaceMaterial>(Node->GetSrcObject<FbxSurfaceMaterial>(0));
                    if (Material) {
                        //
                        //  Diffuse Texture
                        const FbxProperty pDiffuse = Material->FindProperty(FbxSurfaceMaterial::sDiffuse);
                        if (pDiffuse.IsValid()) {
                            const unsigned int layered_texture_count = pDiffuse.GetSrcObjectCount<FbxLayeredTexture>();
                            const unsigned int textureCount = pDiffuse.GetSrcObjectCount<FbxFileTexture>();
                            printf("\tTextures: %i %i\n", layered_texture_count, textureCount);
                            const FbxFileTexture* texture = FbxCast<const FbxFileTexture>(pDiffuse.GetSrcObject<FbxFileTexture>(0));
                            if (texture) {
                                NewFBX->Meshes.back()->Texture_Diffuse = texture->GetRelativeFileName();
                                printf("\tRelative File %s\n", NewFBX->Meshes.back()->Texture_Diffuse);
                            }
                            else { printf("\tTexture Invalid\n"); }
                        }
                        else { printf("\tNo Diffuse\n"); }
                    }
                    else { printf("\tMaterial 1 invalid\n"); }
                    //
                    //
                    const FbxMesh* Mesh = FbxCast<const FbxMesh>(Node->GetNodeAttribute());
                    FbxVector4* Vertices = Mesh->GetControlPoints();
                    //
                    //  UV Mapping *only uses first uv set*
                    FbxStringList lUVSetNameList;
                    Mesh->GetUVSetNames(lUVSetNameList);
                    const unsigned int UVSets = lUVSetNameList.GetCount();
                    printf("\tUV Sets: %i\n", UVSets);
                    const char* lUVSetName = lUVSetNameList.GetStringAt(0);
                    const FbxGeometryElementUV* lUVElement = Mesh->GetElementUV(lUVSetName);
                    bool lUseIndex;
                    int lIndexCount;
                    if (lUVElement) {
                        //if (lUVElement->GetMappingMode() == FbxGeometryElement::eByPolygonVertex) {
                        //printf("\tPolygon Vertex Mapping\n");
                        lUseIndex = lUVElement->GetReferenceMode() != FbxGeometryElement::eDirect;
                        lIndexCount = (lUseIndex) ? lUVElement->GetIndexArray().GetCount() : 0;
                    }
                    //
                    //  Normal Mapping
                    const FbxGeometryElementNormal* lNormalElement = Mesh->GetElementNormal();
                    unsigned int lPolyIndexCounter = 0;
                    uint32_t IndexCount = 0;
                    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < Mesh->GetPolygonCount(); j++) {
                        const unsigned int NumVerts = Mesh->GetPolygonSize(j);
                        if (NumVerts != 3) { continue; }

                        for (unsigned int k = 0; k < NumVerts; k++) {
                            Vertex* NewVertex = new Vertex;
                            //
                            //  Pull Normap Mapping Data
                            int lNormalIndex = 0;
                            // reference mode is direct, the normal index is same as lIndexByPolygonVertex.
                            if (lNormalElement->GetReferenceMode() == FbxGeometryElement::eDirect) {
                                lNormalIndex = lPolyIndexCounter;
                            }
                            // reference mode is index-to-direct, get normals by the index-to-direct
                            else if (lNormalElement->GetReferenceMode() == FbxGeometryElement::eIndexToDirect) {
                                lNormalIndex = lNormalElement->GetIndexArray().GetAt(lPolyIndexCounter);
                            }

                            // Got normals of each polygon-vertex.
                            FbxVector4 lNormal = lNormalElement->GetDirectArray().GetAt(lNormalIndex);

                            NewVertex->normal.x = lNormal[0];
                            NewVertex->normal.y = lNormal[1];
                            NewVertex->normal.z = lNormal[2];
                            //
                            //  Pull Texture UV Mapping Data
                            if (lUVElement) {
                                if (lPolyIndexCounter < lIndexCount)
                                {
                                    //the UV index depends on the reference mode
                                    int lUVIndex = lUseIndex ? lUVElement->GetIndexArray().GetAt(lPolyIndexCounter) : lPolyIndexCounter;

                                    const FbxVector2 lUVValue = lUVElement->GetDirectArray().GetAt(lUVIndex);

                                    NewVertex->texCoord.x = lUVValue.mData[0];
                                    NewVertex->texCoord.y = -lUVValue.mData[1];

                                    lPolyIndexCounter++;
                                }
                            }
                            //
                            //  Pull Vertex & Index data
                            //  ToDo: Remove duplicate vertices using indices
                            const unsigned int Index = Mesh->GetPolygonVertex(j, k);
                            NewVertex->pos.x = (float)(Vertices[Index].mData[0]);
                            NewVertex->pos.y = (float)(Vertices[Index].mData[1]);
                            NewVertex->pos.z = (float)(Vertices[Index].mData[2]);

                            NewFBX->Meshes.back()->Indices.push_back(IndexCount++);
                            NewFBX->Meshes.back()->Vertices.push_back(*NewVertex);
                        }
                    }
                    printf("\tNew Mesh Vertex Count: %zi\n", NewFBX->Meshes.back()->Vertices.size());
                }
                printf("\tOut Mesh Count: %zi\n", NewFBX->Meshes.size());
                return NewFBX;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

EDIT:
I have found scarse examples how to accomplish the task at hand, however this appears to somewhat work but there are a few meshes here and there which are not positioned/rotated/scaled properly. The vertices also appear to have something wrong with them, visually everything looks okay but feeding the vertices into bullet using this method results in some odd physics results, collision objects are somewhat deformed for some if not all meshes whereas the old method resulted in perfectly correct physics objects. nothing has changed aside from adding in the vertice transformations from fbx sdk.

```
            FbxAMatrix matrixGeo;
            matrixGeo.SetIdentity();
            if (Node->GetNodeAttribute())
            {
                const fbxsdk::FbxVector4 lT = Node->GetGeometricTranslation(FbxNode::eSourcePivot);
                const fbxsdk::FbxVector4 lR = Node->GetGeometricRotation(FbxNode::eSourcePivot);
                const fbxsdk::FbxVector4 lS = Node->GetGeometricScaling(FbxNode::eSourcePivot);
                matrixGeo.SetT(lT);
                matrixGeo.SetR(lR);
                matrixGeo.SetS(lS);
            }
            FbxAMatrix globalMatrix = Node->EvaluateGlobalTransform();

            FbxAMatrix matrix = globalMatrix * matrixGeo;
```

and transforming the vertices

```
const unsigned int Index = Mesh->GetPolygonVertex(j, k);
                            //NewVertex->pos.x = (float)(Vertices[Index].mData[0]);
                            //NewVertex->pos.y = (float)(Vertices[Index].mData[1]);
                            //NewVertex->pos.z = (float)(Vertices[Index].mData[2]);
                            fbxsdk::FbxVector4 result = matrix.MultT(Vertices[Index]);
                            NewVertex->pos.x = (float)result.mData[0];
                            NewVertex->pos.y = (float)result.mData[1];
                            NewVertex->pos.z = (float)result.mData[2];

                            NewFBX->Meshes.back()->Indices.push_back(IndexCount++);
                            NewFBX->Meshes.back()->Vertices.push_back(*NewVertex);
```

Reference: https://pybullet.org/Bullet/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=13301

Comment: It might be worth seeing if http://www.assimp.org/ does any better at importing your problematic FBX files. It comes with a model viewer too, so it's easy to try it out and inspect the results.

Comment: Looks fine in assimp, I have a feeling the vertices aren't being transformed properly..